# SVM usage for predicting lost data of Object tracking

Tags: opencv, svm, javacv, prediction

I'm using opencv ,javacv for track an object. i have coordinates of that object path. But some area has not been tracked . i want to predict that lost phases of the path using SVM. Can anyone help to guid me that how can i use svm for my problem? I have no idea about SVM.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you committed to SVM? Your problem seems rather as a simple [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation), **not the machine learning classification**. If you have discontinued paths it may be enough to simply interpolate missing points with fitting some simple function (like line or some kind of spline).